# how can I compare some field at list and insert it's values, in another list?

Tags: java, arraylist, compare

I have two lists first `List<ClassOne>` and second `List<ClassTwo>`.
ClassOne has the following fields:

ClassOne:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class ClassOne {
    private Integer idToInsert;
    private String fieldToCompare;
    private List<AnotherClass> anotherClass;
}
```

And ClassTwo has the following fields:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class ClassTwo {

    private Integer idToInsert;
    private String fieldToCompare;

}
```

And I have this two Lists `List<ClassOne>` and `List<ClassTwo>`.
`ClassTwo` contains the `idToInsert` field, which must be inserted in `ClassOne`, when the `fieldToCompare` field is the same in both classes.

Something like

```
if(classtwo.getFieldToCompare.equals(classOne.getFieldTocompare){
  classOne.setIdToInsert(classTwo.getIdToInsert());
}
```

How can I do this comparing this two lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest to collect `List<ClassTwo>` into `Map<String,Integer>` which is `Map(fieldToCompare, idToInsert)` for better performance

```
Map<String,Integer> classTwoMap = classTwoList.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(two->two.getFieldToCompare(), two->two.getIdToInsert()));
```

And then now just use `forEach` on `classListOne`

```
classListOne.forEach(one -> one.setidToInsert(classTwoMap.getOrDefault(one.getFieldTocompare(),one.getIdToInsert())));
```